# Xamarin.Android - Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, ssl-certificate, mobile-development

So I'm working on a Xamarin app and all was going great until yesterday.

However, since yesterday I can't log in to the web server on my app and get this error when I do:

"java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found"

On the iOS side of things there is no problem, log in works just fine. No code was changed on Android for this to happen, it just started happening yesterday with no changes made.

The app has it's own class replacing AndroidClientHandler and isn't using the default AndroidClientHandler.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images

Comment: there are also hundreds of existing questions and posts about this error.  Have you reviewed them?

Comment: Yep I have, nothing really that's helped me so far...

Comment: have you checked your server's certificate?  There are numerous online tools for testing certs

Comment: Trying to get the SSL server domain to check it. However, this seems to only happen on my device. Tested on colleagues device and they don't have this problem.

Comment: Did you try to uninstall the the application on your device and then debug it?

Comment: Yes I have. Upon further inspection I think I know where it stems from but not too sure how to go about fixing it. On the method that loads the KeyStore I get an error "Java.IO.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/files/xxx.ServerCerts: open failed". Any idea how to go about fixing this?

Comment: Forgot to add - ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: When you reinstalled the application, did the error show? In addition, where does the certification locate?

Comment: Yes the error showed. In terms of it's location I'm not too sure it's a small corporate project.

Comment: Did you check the path when you run it on your colleaguess' device?